# Fields getting the same value on click

Tags: jquery

I have 4 textfields with class cup. I want the different fields to get different value every time I will click the number button.

Below is my code:

```
$(".cup").focus(function(){
    var xfield = $(this);
    keypad(xfield);
})

function keypad(xfield)
{
   $(".numbtn").click(function(){
      var number = $(this).text();
      xfield.val(number);
    })
}
```

Comment: what is `numbtn` ? could you please share your html code also?

Comment: It would be better if you could post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of it.

Comment: use id instead of class
$("#cup").focus(function(){
    var xfield = $(this);
    keypad(xfield);
})

Comment: this is the link of my code to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hjch9d50/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: you can store clicked `cup` fields in a variable and when you click on `numbtn` then set its value, see below code

```
$(function(){
  var $clickedCup = $(".cup:first"); // variable to store clicked cup, default is first cup
  $(".cup").focus(function(){
      $clickedCup = $(this);
   });

   $(".numbtn").click(function(){
      var number = $(this).text();
      $clickedCup.val(number);//set value of clicked number
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".numbtn").click(function () {
        $('.cup').each(function(){
            var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
            $(this).val(number);
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var xfield;
        $(".cup").focus(function () {
            xfield = $(this);
        })
        $(".numbtn").click(function () {
            if ($(xfield).length == 0)
                {
                xfield = $(".cup:first");
                }
        $(xfield).val($(this).val());

        })
    });
```